# Picking two different images in the same view controller using imagePickerController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making an app in which there are two UIImageViews. In each image view the user needs to be able to input a different image. Here is the code I have so far.

```
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBAction func chooseImage1(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
        println("Button capture")


        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func chooseImage2(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
        println("Button capture")


        imagePicker2.delegate = self
        imagePicker2.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker2.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        chooseImage1.image = pickedImage

    let pickedImage2 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    chooseImage2.image = pickedImage2



    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

This ends up picking the same image for each different image view. I would like to be able to choose two individual photos, one for each view. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You only need one UIImagePickerController. You can keep a reference of the tapped view and when the user finish picking the image, you just need to cast the selected view as UIImageView and set its image property:

update: **Xcode 11.5 • Swift 5.2 or later**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var selectedView: UIView!
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        
        [imageView1,imageView2].forEach {
            $0?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            $0?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(chooseImage)))
        }
    }
    
    @objc func chooseImage(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) {
            selectedView = gesture.view
            present(imagePicker, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        (selectedView as? UIImageView)?.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: "selectedVew" typo was making me scratch my head til I spotted it, I had "selectedView" too...  Works beautifully thanks! 