# Both UIImage displaying different image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I am adding 2 function `UITapGestureRecognizer` for my 2 `UIImage` for displaying diffrent picture each `UIImage`.

So when I tap one of my `UIImage`, `UIAlertController` will show and give 2 option for adding a picture (using Camera or using Library)

But when I'm adding the picture, both of them is displaying same picture (when I using `imagePickerController`

and after I add `if else` statement, the picture is only displayed on `if` statement even when I tap on the second `UIImage`

For example:

I've 2 `UIImage` named `imageView1.image` and `imageView2.image`

I tap on my first `imageView1.image`, `UIAlertController` does show option (camera and library)
I choose library and select image1.jpg

After i select image1.jpg, both `imageView1.image` and `imageView2.image` displaying same picture.

After I'm adding `if else` statement in the `func imagePickerController`, the image1.jpg is only displayed on the `if` statement... Even i tap on the `imageVIew2.image`

But, what I want is...
When i tap `imageView1.image` and select image1.jpg, `imageView1.image` displaying image1.jpg and `imageView2.jpg` isnt displaying anything.

Here's my code (without if else):

```
extension KUYPEP {

//pencetGambarnya1 for imageView1.image
@objc func pencetGambarnya1(tapGestureRecognizer1: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePickerController.delegate = self

            let gambarDipencet1 = tapGestureRecognizer1.view as! UIImageView


            let act1 = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)


            act1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {

                    imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera;

                    self.present (imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {


                    print ("Camera ruksak")

                }
            }))

            act1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in

                imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

                self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }))

            act1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(UIAlertAction)in}))


            self.present(act1, animated: true, completion: nil)

            print ("berhasil11")


        }



//pencetGambarnya2 for imageView2.image
    @objc func pencetGambarnya2(tapGestureRecognizer2: UITapGestureRecognizer) {



        let imagePickerController2 = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController2.delegate = self

        let gambarDipencet2 = tapGestureRecognizer2.view as! UIImageView


        let act2 = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)


        act2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {

                imagePickerController2.sourceType = .camera;

                self.present (imagePickerController2, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {


                print ("Camera ruksak")

            }
        }))

        act2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in

            imagePickerController2.sourceType = .photoLibrary

            self.present(imagePickerController2, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        act2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(UIAlertAction)in}))


        self.present(act2, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print ("berhasil22")

    }



    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

            let image1 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            imageView1.image = image1





        let image2 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView2.image = image2



        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        print ("Slavic Hardbass")
    }



    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

And here's my `viewDidLoad`

```
let tapGestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pencetGambarnya1(tapGestureRecognizer1:)))

    imageView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer1)



    let tapGestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pencetGambarnya2(tapGestureRecognizer2:)))

    imageView2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer2)
```

Comment: In `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])` you set both image views to selected image. so of course both have the same image that is what your code does

Comment: I'm just realize it when i'm debugging it, but I don't know how to set each one using if else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by adding `var` in the class using this code

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657269/picking-two-different-images-in-the-same-view-controller-using-imagepickercontro?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Thank you for replying.

Comment: please explain the solution in detail. And if any of the answers solved your problem, please mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm using this method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657269/picking-two-different-images-in-the-same-view-controller-using-imagepickercontro?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I don't know how to mark this answer as accepted...

Comment: @Renziz, you can provide the referred link in answer and mark own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Create one public UIImage named targetImage and do like the following,
assign the reference of image1 or image2 to targetImage just before presenting imagePickerController. When finished picking the image, just set the picked image to targetImage. You can see in the following code, i have set targetImage = imageView1.

```
act1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {

                    imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera;
                    targetImage = imageView1
                    self.present (imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {


                    print ("Camera ruksak")

                }
            }))
```

And do the same for imageView2 as well, 
After that modify code to set picked media like this,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

            let image1 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            targetImage.image = image1

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        print ("Slavic Hardbass")
    }
```

I have not tested this, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code. Hope it works for you

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if picker == imagePickerController
    {
         let image1 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
         imageView1.image = image1
    }
   else
    {
        let image2 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView2.image = image2
    }

   picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print ("Slavic Hardbass")
}
```