# how do I add a cover image

Tags: swift, xcode

I can get it to pick the same image as the profile image but I don't want that I want the cover image be a Different image if you need a screenshot I can get one for you  please help [this what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwVhv.jpg)

```
  let CoverButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_selected").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(r: 188, g: 224, b: 253)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 204)
    return button
}()



let plusPhotoButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_selected").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(r: 188, g: 224, b: 253)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePlusPhoto), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 14, y: 231, width: 56, height: 56)


    return button
}()



@objc func handlePlusPhoto() {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        plusPhotoButton.setImage(editedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        plusPhotoButton.setImage(originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    }

    plusPhotoButton.layer.cornerRadius = plusPhotoButton.frame.width/2
    plusPhotoButton.layer.masksToBounds = true

    dismis
```

Comment: A cover image to what Donnie? You need to provide more information in your question title and body.

Comment: cover image like facebook or twitter

Comment: look at the image I just post

Comment: as of right now is your imagePickerController just setting a profile image?

Comment: is the profile image the plusPhotoButton?

Comment: yes I know when I add the cover button to it to make the cover image the same  as profile

Comment: yes is it the cover image is the cover button

Comment: Okay i see what you need to do here. This is an issue with how you are handling info in the imagePickerController function.

Comment: I answered your question. Let me know if that is what you are looking for

Comment: @A.Petrizza no it did't work don't know it because I'm not calling the sender.tag

Comment: If you dont want to send it then you dont have to. Set a variable to hold the sender.tag value and then do an if check on the value in the Imagepickercontroller function

Comment: @A.Petrizza thank you so much for the help I got it to work thank you again

Comment: I updated my answer below, if it is correct to what you needed to do, mark it as correct and we are all done here :)

Comment: And not a problem, it was my pleasure. I need that karma to come back to me with coding trouble later ;) ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to add the target to your CoverButton.
Go and add a tag to your two buttons. Inside this function below do a check to something of this effect:

If you dont want to send a tag value to the function, create a variable to hold the value of the tag, and check it inside the function below.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

if tagValue == 1 {
   if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
    coverButton.setImage(editedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
} else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
    coverButton.setImage(originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
   }
    coverButton.layer.cornerRadius = plusPhotoButton.frame.width/2
    coverButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
} else if OTHERBUTTONTAG

"Do the same as above but for your plusPhotoButton"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the question is about how to use the same imagePickerController for two different images in the same view controller?

Check this answer out, and hopefully that will help you out: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30657560/5858330