# How to allow user to change profile picture and cover photo in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am coding swift in Xcode and trying to create an Edit User Profile ViewController that has two UIImageViews, one UIImageView is for the profile photo and the other if for the cover photo. I am having a hard time changing images for the cover photo. When I go in my simulator and click on the change cover photo button and choose an image it changes the profile photo. When I click on the change profile photo button and choose an image it also changes the profile image as well but this action is correct. Does anyone know how to help me to where I can change images for these controllers and not have them be the same image? This is my code below.

```swift
import UIKit

class profilephotoViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var profileImagePhoto: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageTapped: UIButton!

    var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!


    @IBOutlet weak var coverImagePhoto: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var coverImageTapped: UIButton!

    var secondImagePicker:UIImagePickerController!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openImagePicker))
        profileImagePhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        profileImagePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
        profileImagePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = profileImagePhoto.bounds.height / 2
        profileImagePhoto.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImageTapped.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)


        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self


        let coverTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openSecondImagePicker))
        coverImagePhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        coverImagePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(coverTap)
        coverImagePhoto.clipsToBounds = true
        coverImageTapped.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSecondImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)

        secondImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        secondImagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        secondImagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        secondImagePicker.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func openImagePicker(_ sender:Any) {
        //Open Image Picker
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func openSecondImagePicker(_ sender:Any) {
        //Open Second Image Picker
         self.present(secondImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension profilephotoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            self.profileImagePhoto.image = pickedImage 
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func secondImagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    internal func secondImagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let secondPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            self.coverImagePhoto.image = secondPickedImage   
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no `secondImagePickerController` delegate method you need to handle both callbacks inside `imagePickerController`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657269/picking-two-different-images-in-the-same-view-controller-using-imagepickercontro/30657560

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

       if let secondPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {

          if let picker == imagePicker  {
              self.profileImagePhoto.image = secondPickedImage
          }
          else {
              self.coverImagePhoto.image = secondPickedImage   
          } 

       }

       picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```